# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetComName referenced in function "private: int __cdecl StartProcess::ComInit(void)"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator 4.10.0 in 64-bit windows 7. when I compile my project(the complier is 32-bit, this problem occurs:

```
startprocess.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__imp_GetComName referenced in function "private: int __cdecl 
StartProcess::ComInit(void)" (?ComInit@StartProcess@@AEAAHXZ)
```

My pro file

```
LIBS += -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/boost_1_71_0/libs" - 
    llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x32-1_71 \
    - 
     L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/boost_1_71_0/libs" - 
      llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-x32-1_71 \
    -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" - 
      lEfuseLibrary \
    -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" -lQMTRACE \
    -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" - 
       lDownloadLib
```

Comment: Qt 4.10 or QtCreator 4.10?

Comment: QtCreator 4.10.0  The IDE is QT creator. I include all the lib but still get this error.